# How to add custom html inside form

Tags: 6, forms

I need to put some custom html tags and code inside the form elements am creating using form api .  I defined a fieldset and need to come the html under this fieldset , code sample :

```
  $general_wb_vars = array(
        'wb_debug'=>array('type'=>'select','values'=>'ERR,OFF','default_value'=>'OFF','label'=>'Debug','description'=>''),
        'wb_cache'=>array('type'=>'radio','values'=>'Yes,No','default_value'=>'No','label'=>'Cache','description'=>''),
        'wb_ip'=>array('type'=>'textfield','values'=>'','default_value'=>'192.168.1.1','label'=>'IP','description'=>'')
        );
        $numofrepeat = 4;
        if($form_id=='my-form-id'){
                $form['fieldsetm'] = array('#type' => 'fieldset',
                                         '#title' => t('Weblogic configurations'),
                                         '#weight' => 10,
                                );

                for($i=1;$i<=$numofrepeat;$i++){
                foreach($general_wb_vars as $id => $setts){
                   $form['fieldsetm']['field_p_'.$id.'['.$i.'][value]'] = array('#type' => $setts['type'],
                                        '#title' => t($setts['label']),
                                        '#default_value' => $setts['default_value'],
                                        '#description' => t($setts['description']),
                                        '#attributes' => array('id'=>$id.$i),

                                  );
                                if($setts['type']=='select'){
                                        $form['fieldsetm']['field_p_'.$id.'['.$i.'][value]']['#options'] = explode(',',$setts['values']);                                      }
                                if($setts['type']=='radio')
                                        $form['filedsetm']['field_p_'.$id.'['.$i.'][value]']['#values'] = explode(',',$setts['values']);
                                        $form['fieldsetm']['some_markup'] = array(
                                           '#type' => 'item',
                                           '#markup' => '---------------------------------------------------------------------',
                                         );
                                }                               
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at Drupal 7 form api reference perhaps. For drupal 6 according to the [form api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#markup) you just need to put your HTML string in `#value` as the default D6 `#type` is `markup`